# MATLAB - Docking figure

Tags: matlab, plot, script

Can I see the editor and the plot in MatLab (docked view) in parallel?

This function doesn't work any longer and it was partially what I needed.

```
set(h, 'WindowStyle', 'Docked');
```

I don't want to arrange it manually all the time to get this.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, despite your name, this question has nothing to do with electrical engineering. Maybe you'd better post this on math.stackexchange.com, but check the site's rules if this question fits there

Comment: @Huisman it has the right name and tags, nothing misleading in my opinion.

Comment: except this is a program query rather than an electrical query using a program. Either way just drag the figure into the workspace and it will dock

Comment: that's what what I've done for this example picture. It doesn't stay there @JonRB

Comment: now save that layout.